# SQL Server CASE in ORDER BY clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this `ORDER BY` clause here:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @isAlphabeticalSort = 1 THEN itemName ELSE itemId END
```

I have `@isAlphabeticalSort` defined in my stored procedure like so:

```
@isAlphabeticalSort bit = 1
```

When I run my stored procedure with `@isAlphabeticalSort` set to 0:

```
@isAlphabeticalSort = 0
```

It works as expected, when I set it to 1 when I run my stored procedure, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I also have the red line under `@isAlphabeticalSort = 0` says:

> @isAlphabeticalSort is not a parameter in the procedure

My question is, am I defining my bool wrong? Is my case in my order by clause wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the `datatype` of your `columns` itemName and itemId?

Comment: both columns need to have the same type, you could convert ItemID to varchar perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `CASE` expression, the datatype that is attempted to be returned with be the datatype with the highest data type precedence. In this case you have 2 columns in your `CASE` expression `itemName` (which I assume is a `varchar`) and `itemID` (which I assume in an `datetime`). `datetime` has a higher precendence, so any return values will be implicitly converted to an `datetime`, if they aren't already.

The correct way, therefore, to do this would be:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @isAlphabeticalSort = 1 THEN itemName END,
         CASE WHEN @isAlphabeticalSort = 0 THEN itemId END, --As recommended by @JamesZ
         [Other Columns];
```

For reference:
[Data Type Precendence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) and
[CASE (Transact-SQL): Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#return-types)

Comment: @user979331 Good - now can you mark the response as the answer?

Comment: For cases where there's something after these in the order by, the second part could also have `case when @isAlphabeticalSort = 0 then ItemID end`

Comment: Nice addition @JamesZ.

Answer (score 2):

Both columns need to have the same type, you can try something like this

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @isAlphabeticalSort = 1 THEN itemName 
              ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), itemId, 102) -- as recommended by Lamu
              END
```

Comment: Although this might work, this might not sort correctly. If `ItemId` is an `int`, for example, then `'9' > '21'`. You should also declare the length of your `varchar`.

Comment: This works, itemId is actually a date, I changed the name of column to something simple for the example

Comment: @Larnu Yes you are correct, but since his datatype seems to be a Date this does not matter anymore I guess

Comment: if it's a date, then i would at least use `CONVERT(varchar(10), itemId ,102)`, as this will sort in the same order; as it forces the format `yyyy.MM.dd`.

Comment: Trying to remember order of precedence, while impressive here at StackOverflow, is probably not the best practice in the real world. I either use parenthesis or a cast/convert to force the result that I need.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits not sure I agree with you there. Data Type Precedence is pretty vital to SQL Server to ensure that the intended outcome is given. Using `CAST` & `CONVERT` affects SARGability, especially in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, so I'd strongly suggest that your comment is wrong; it is very important to consider it for best practice in the real world.

Comment: Order precedence is important but maintainability is just as important. My philosophy is that programs should be obvious and maintainable. I teach tsql and perhaps 10-20% of developers have memorized precedence order. I don't want to engage in personal attacks (or be the victims of people questioning my sql knowledge) but if you work in a typical shop don't depend on other users knowing these rules offhand. This is in order by which I am not sure is affected by SARG. I was under the impression SARG is mainly an issue in query plans and joins.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to your columns itemName (varchar ?) and itemId (int ?). You can only use the same datatype in Case statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#arguments

"The data types of else_result_expression and any result_expression must be the same or must be an implicit conversion."

Comment: itemId is actually a date I just changed the name to something simple for the example

Comment: SQL Server generally takes the type from the first param provided(itemName) which is a varchar. You may try THEN itemName ELSE  cast (itemId  as varchar(20))

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits when does it? It completely depends on the function. `CASE` for example uses the highest data precendence, while `ISNULL` uses the first parameter's datatype. Thus `COALESCE('a',1)` will fail (`COALESCE` is short had for a `CASE`), while `ISNULL('a',1)` will not.